# How not to create duplicates in a task "Create work item" in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have pipeline in azure devops. In this pipeline i use task "Create work item", how i can not to create duplicates with the same name ?
I use classic editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to duplicates parametr this value "System.Title" and duplicates not creates

Answer (score 0):

> How not to create duplicates in a task "Create work item" in azure devops

You could define an auto-incrementing variable for the name of the workitem.

In this case, the name of each created workitem will be accompanied by an auto-increment variable to distinguish it:

```
InternalWorkItemID 1

semanticWorkItemID $[counter(variables['InternalWorkItemID'], 0)]
```

[image]

[image]

The test result:

[image]

Besides, we could also define the 2022310 as variable and enable **Settable at queue time**：

[image]

[image]

We could update the `WorkItemTitle` at queue the pipeline:

[image]

**In this case**, even if we forget to modify the name of the workitem, there is still a self-increment to distinguish.